# Floor Value of an element in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

So I was reading the book - Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy by Narasimha Karumanchi and in that  the floor Value of a bst snippet is given - Problem 61 in BST Chapter.
The snippet confused me very much and now I just want to know how it is working :
The snippet as Follows :

```
node* floorValue(node* root, node* prev ,int k)
{
    if(!root){
        return NULL;
    }

    if( !(floorValue(root->left , prev ,k))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(root->data == k)
    {
        return root;
    }
    if(root->data > k)
    {
        return prev;
    }
    prev = root;
    return floorValue(root->right , prev , k);
}
```

In this the `node* prev` which is initiated with `NULL` is storing the previous node and `int k` is the integer for which we are finding the floor value.

Can someone please help me in understanding its recursion. I am confused because :

1 . The code :  `if( !(floorValue(root->left , prev ,k)) { return 0; }`
will return 0 when the left most of the element of the tree is hit. But that will trigger all the recursive calls return 0.

2. Why it's returning 0 when we are returning the `node*` and not any `int`

Help will be really appreciated. I have solved this question but it was not using this method but a more straight forward one ( according to me ). I want to know what am I doing wrong or what I am missing in this code.

*Input:
The First input will be the number of nodes:
The next n lines will be the nodes data. The first input after n will be the root value.*

FULL CODE:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int data;
  node* left;
  node* right;
};

node* insertBST(node* root , int x)
{

    if(root==NULL)
    {
        node* root= new node;
        root->data = x;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    else
    {
        if(x <root->data)
        {
            root->left = insertBST(root->left , x);
        }
        else
        {
            root->right = insertBST(root->right , x);
        }

    }
}

void inorder(node* root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        cout<<root->data<<" ";
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

node* floorValue(node* root, node* prev ,int k)
{
    if(!root){
        return NULL;
    }

    if( !(floorValue(root->left , prev ,k))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(root->data == k)
    {
        return root;
    }
    if(root->data > k)
    {
        return prev;
    }
    prev = root;
    return floorValue(root->right , prev , k);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    node *root = new node;
    root = NULL;
    for(int i = 0 ;i<n;i++)
    {
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        root= insertBST(root , k);
    }

    inorder(root);
    
    cout<<"\nEnter the Value for which floor has to be searched : ";
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    
    node* prev = NULL;
    cout<<floorValue(root , prev, k);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is exactly the same as given in the book except some variable names.

Thank You and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the initial value of prev?

Comment: @YashShah it's NULL.

Comment: What do you mean by "floor value of an element"?  If it's simply the smallest value in a binary search tree, that's just a matter of going left on the tree until a leaf node is reached.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I guess something like this: for the given BST with elements 1, 3, 5, 7 and the given value 4, return 3.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Yes, it is as explained by Evg. And suppose the bst is - 3 5 7 9 and the given value is 2 then it will return NULL , as there will be no floor value of that.

Comment: So it is basically an inorder traversal, and saving the last visited node's value comparing it to the test value.  That's what it boils down to and what the current code seems to be doing.  Except for C++ related issues with the code such as returning `NULL` and `0` instead of `nullptr`, what is basically not being understood by the code?

Comment: Yes that's what is confusing me. As for the 1st confusion (in the question above )I can't understand how that is going to let the code flow beyond that point. I mean if I am returning 0 from the left most node of the tree then it is going to return back 0 as the answer. Right? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it is similar to inorder traversal, not exactly . Everytime we enter the func we check for its left node. So this goes on recursively and returns 0 right?

Comment: I think this snippet doesn't perform the required task. Or am i missing something?

Comment: No, it should exactly be an inorder traversal, not similar.  The only difference is the "predicate" function being applied to the node once it is visited.  If the traversal is to continue for whatever reason, then the `right` branch is selected, otherwise no branch is selected (a simple `return`).  That's how you make searching and operation generic.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean it the logic wise, but functionality wise what O.P felt (recursion and returning 0) is correct right?

Comment: It looks right to me, but not tested.  The generic logic of an in-order traversal is 1) Test for a null node, if null return.  2) Go left.  3) Do something with the node data (it doesn't matter what it is -- take inventory, record its value, do something complicated, etc.).  3) If traversal is to stop, do a simple return.  If traversal is to continue, take the right branch.  The code snippet seems to be following that pattern correctly, thus it should work.  Maybe if @SayantoRoy looked at it this way, generically, it may be understood how it works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well When I am trying to run it, exactly the same code - it is always returning 0 . Doesn't matter what I put in the input.

Comment: @SayantoRoy -- There is no program to run since you did not post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you just help me to know how the program will get beyond that `if ( !floorValue(root->left, prev, k ) ) ` . Because at the leftmost node it will return NULL to that  If statement and that will satisfy it and thus will return 0. And recursively the If statement that called it will also satisfy and return 0 and so on... Till the O/P will be returned as 0.  This is where I am confused and totally missing something.

Comment: @SayantoRoy You claimed the code you posted is working and wanted to understand how it works.  Then you are now claiming it doesn't work?  If it does work, you should simply take your program and run it in a debugger, going a single-step at a time and follow the flow.

Comment: @SayantoRoy, I am sure your claim is correct, but once put the entire code, so I can once test it

Comment: @SaiSreenivas I have added the full code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I never claimed it worked. I just have said that it is given in the book ... I said I have solved the question with a different approach. Thank You For your help. I will use the debugger to see it's flow.

Comment: @SayantoRoy, your claim is correct, this code doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's classic Binary Search algorithm. I always recommend you to understand the problem you posted. If you clear with algorithm you will know how Binary Search actualy works, as well as how Backtrack works using StackTrace of your system/computer memory.

Let's dive into that. :)

```
if(!root){
    return NULL;
}
```

the above code snippet, is the case, if you reach here, it is guranteed you searched all the possibilities, but didn't find the 'key' you want. :(

```
if( !(floorValue(root->left , prev ,k))
{
    return NULL; 
}
```

Remember you should return NULL, instead of return 0, since the return value of your function is actually NULL, (though both 0/NULL defines the false case in c/c++, prematurely you can use any of it.

Now you can see, you are diving into the function, with root->left, means left-part of Tree are checking first, similar to Binary Search, where you are searching left side of your input elements.

```
if(root->data == k)
{
    return root;
}
```

If you reach here, congrats, you finally reached into your destination :D, other words, you found your result in huge (or small, whatever) input elements.

```
if(root->data > k)
{
    return prev;
}
```

The above snippent is same when your middle elements are greater than your key, so you know you have to go left side of your inputs. (going right will always give you Sadness, you will ended up with nothing).

```
 prev = root;
return floorValue(root->right , prev , k);
```

The above code are telling you, you went left, but got 0 (you ended up with failure to find the result), so you need to go right side now.

Now most importantly, understand these two following snippets ::

```
if(root->data > k)
{
    return prev;
}
```

and

```
 prev = root;
 return floorValue(root->right , prev , k);
```

The above two snippets not only dive you into left or right part of your tree (or inputs) but also checking each and every left and right node of your left Tree, and right and left of your right Tree.

When its failed to get the key you want, it's backtrack to your place where you started to go into LEFT (it's kind of DARK series, let's assume left is PAST here, :D right?? ) now you have to go to future, that's RIGHT, to find out the key.

you get the key ? return it from the left(past), or go to right(future) again.

you will definitely reach a conclusion, either SUCCESS or FAILURE.

enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet you found is awful, but the answer to your questions is that `return 0` is the same as `return NULL` -- it's not an integer, it's a null pointer.  The code is supposed to return null if there is no node in the tree <= the search value.

Here's a much better implementation:

```
Node* floorNode(Node* tree, int k) {
    Node *flr = NULL;
    while(tree) {
        if (tree -> data <= k) {
            flr = tree;
            tree = tree->right;
        } else {
            tree = tree->left;
        }
    }
    return flr;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know but that was given in a book so I asked that. I thought I was missing something in that. I have already solved the problem using the same approach as you have given. Thank You for the answer.